# Analysis of NAND-based low-power monostable circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, multivibrator, monostable, one-shot

I've seen a monostable multivibrator circuit shown below. The purpose of the circuit is to provide a power to a circuit for an amount of time controlled by potentiometer after pressing the momentary pushbutton. The power supply connected with a 1k resistor is a load circuit. The second power supply is designed for powering the monostable circuit. I created an simulation from the circuit photo and it consumes very low current (few nA), it is much less than CMOS NE555 or CD4541. Could someone explain the principles of operation of this system and its possible disadvantages/drawbacks?
[image]

Link to the simulation: http://tinyurl.com/25jcl3kw

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271306/monostable-out-of-nand-gates  and this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279167/how-to-calculate-the-time-constant-tau-for-a-digital-circuit/279176#279176

Comment: I don't think your simulation incorporates the quiescent current of these logic gates, which will indeed be very low, but not zero. I think that because Falstad doesn't actually allow me to pick a logic family, but just allows for usage of the "perfect" gate.

Comment: (generally, logic gates that output high at 5 V tend to be "old"-family compatible or simply old. Their typical supply current without doing anything is in the order of 1 to 10 µA for a quad-gate package; not nA)

Comment: The nand gates could be CD4093. I checked that it's maximal current Is 1uA. Yes this circuit will take more current than I thought. Thank you for this.

Comment: The best option would to have the circuit that doesn't need a own battery but could take an load supply. But the polarity of the load power supply is not known, it can vary with different speciments so it's impossible to project.

Comment: Thanks also to @G36 for the materials.

Comment: @JSK note that the lower a supply voltage you can use, the less current these devices will in general draw; with something less ancient than the CD40 series, like, say, an SN74HCS00, you'd be able to run at Vcc = 2V (and very very minimal supply current)  ; you'd need some MOSFETs with low V_(GS, threshold), but these are abundant and cheap.

Comment: @JSK the other recommendation of course is to use a much smaller capacitor value and accordingly scale your resistors inversely; that will reduce the amount of energy per switching cycle.

Comment: To facilitate a circuit discussion, please repost the schematic with a unique reference designator for each component.

Comment: @AnalogKid Thank you, the post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most monostable circuits are based on a property of capacitors - the voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantaneously.  Thus, if you yank one end of a cap from one voltage to another rapidly, the other end of the cap will change by the same amount.  If it was at a different potential before the yank, as coupling capacitors often are, the potential difference across the cap will be maintained briefly before the circuit currents work to stabilize the cap an new, post-yank voltages.

U1 is a logic gate, so its output has only two (idealized) valid states:  Vcc and GND.  When the circuit is at rest and S1 is open, P1 holds the inputs to U1B low, so its output is high, so both inputs to U1A are high, so the U1A output is low.  Thus, C3 has 0 V across it; both sides are at GND.

When S1 closes, the logic low at U1A propagates around the positive feedback loop and appears at the other U1A input as a low:  U1A out goes high, both sides of the cap go high (see above), the inputs to U1B go high, U1B out goes low, and that low is fed back to a U1A input.  This is the start of the timing period.

Because of how a NAND gate functions, this low holds the loop in this "triggered" state even if S1 is opened, or bounces, or is pressed multiple times.  The 100% positive feedback loop that is a characteristic of a "true" monostable causes a kind of input lockout during the timing period.

All of that happens in less than 1 microsecond after S1 closes.  Now the timing starts to happen.  When the right side of C3 snaps high, it immediately begins to charge down through P1, causing the voltage at the U1B inputs to decrease slowly.  How slowly?  That is the what makes this circuit useful.

Terminology:  Charging down and discharging are not the same thing.  In discharging, the total charge in the cap is decreasing, as is the voltage across it.  In charging down, the charge in the cap is increasing, but the voltage at the end we are interested in is decreasing with respect to GND because that end of the cap was at Vcc with zero charge in it.  The voltage across the cap is increasing, but since the positive end is clamped at Vcc, the U1B inputs see a downward voltage slope.

All logic gates have an input characteristic called the threshold voltage, the input voltage at which the gate "sees" a change from one logic level to another.  In your circuit you have Schmitt trigger gates that have two threshold voltages, but that does not affect the basic operation of the circuit.  The U1B input voltage decreases exponentially, at a rate determined by the values of P1 and C3.  Eventually, the decreasing cap voltage moves through the gate threshold voltage.  While its input voltage continues downward toward GND, the U2B output goes high.  This is the end of the timing period.

The timing period ends no matter the state of S1.  At this point there is 5 V across C3, and this needs to be discharged to 0 V for the next timing cycle to be accurate.  How the circuit resets itself does depend on S1.  If S1 is open, both inputs to U1A now are high, and its output goes low.  yanking the left side of C3 low means yanking the right side from GND to -Vcc, again because the voltage across a cap cannot change infinitely fast.  -Vcc is a bad thing to apply to the input of any logic gate.  While many logic types have internal protection against ESD transients of both polarities, often these structures cannot handle the energy dump of a large timing capacitor.  D3 protects against this damage.  D3 begins to conduct at around -0.6 V, clamping the U1B inputs at a safe level and basically short-circuiting C3 down to 0.6 V across it.  After that, P1 discharges C3 the rest of the way down to 0 V.  If S1 is closed immediately after a timing period ends, the residual charge in C3 will mean a shorter timing cycle.

If S1 is closed at the end of a timing cycle, the U1A output remains high and the circuit is parked with 5 V across C3.  When S1 is opened, the circuit will reset as above.  This can be important, because at first glance it appears that the U1A output is identical to the U1B output, but inverted.  It is, but only if S1 is open at the end of the timing period.

With appropriate logic level shifts, this circuit can be adapted to work with any type of logic gate.  The only criteria is that the the loop be non-inverting.  Thus, two AND, OR, or NOR gates will work.  Two simple inverters also will work with the addition of 1 resistor and 1 diode.
.